# Ubuntu 20 USB device descriptor read/8, error -110

Tags: usb, 20.04, dell, power-management, docking

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20 on my Dell Laptop 2 days ago. I do have a Dell Display link docking station. I am experiencing the device descriptor error as mentioned in the subject.

When that happens, only the laptop keyboard and the touch pad works for me. No other USB port on my laptop works for me.

Previously I was using Ubuntu 20, but that was a migration from the Ubuntu 18 LTS. There I had no such issue before.

```
[ 8270.247510] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd
[ 8275.503438] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 8291.118961] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 8291.227112] usb usb1-port9: attempt power cycle
[ 8291.879114] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 17 using xhci_hcd
[ 8297.135243] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 8302.511250] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 8302.750767] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 18 using xhci_hcd
[ 8307.887137] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 8313.263174] usb 1-9: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[ 8313.370569] usb usb1-port9: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I read several threads saying this is related to some power issue. The advice in those threads is to reboot the machine. Yes, I know that can solve the problem but for me this problems happens again after some time.

Can some one help me understand what is the real issue? I do not suppose that there is any issue with the power supplied by my docking station as it was working fine before 2 days.